# VB6 Compare list1 and list2 and remove unwanted items from list2

Tags: vb6

I am trying to compare 2 listbox in vb6,list2 items should match items in list1 then remove un-matched strings from list2.

list1 items:

```
ls-05
ls-06
ls-12
mg_01.rom
mg_02.rom
mg_05.rom
mg_06.rom
mg_m07.rom
mg_m08.rom
mg_m09.rom
mg_m10.rom
mg_m11.rom
mg_m12.rom
mg_m13.rom
mg_m14.rom
```

list2 items:

```
ls-05
ls-05.12e
ls-06
ls-06.10e
ls-11
ls-11.2l
ls-12
ls-12.7l
mg_01.rom
mg_02.rom
mg_05.rom
mg_06.rom
mg_m07.rom
mg_m07.rom2
mg_m08.rom
mg_m08.rom3
mg_m09.rom
mg_m09.rom2
mg_m10.rom
mg_m10.rom3
mg_m11.rom
mg_m11.rom0
mg_m12.rom
mg_m12.rom1
mg_m13.rom
mg_m13.rom0
mg_m14.rom
mg_m14.rom1
```

button code:

```
For ii = List1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    For i = List1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If List1.List(i) = List2.List(ii) Then Exit For ' no need to keep looping, its a match. i will be > -1
    Next
    If i = -1 Then ' all items in list1 were searched, but no matches found, so remove it
        List2.RemoveItem ii
    End If
Next
```

so the end results I am after is list2 should have same items removing other junk strings that did not match.

Comment: Shouldn't `For ii = List1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1` be `For ii = List2.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1` ie `List2`

Comment: Its not clear what your actual question is? Are you just looking for a code review?

Answer (score 1):

Using Strings and InStrB() function:

```
dim lstitm as string, str2 as string, count as integer

count = list2.listcount

for i = 0 to count - 1
  str2 = str2 & list2.list(i) & ";"
next i

list2.clear

count = list1.listcount

for i = 0 to count -1
 lstitm = list1.list(i)
 if instrb(1,str2,lstitm) <> 0 then list2.additem lstitm
next i
```